# Laravel 4 deletion by id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I can't find a way to delete my news. It returns me an 404 (not found) error.

my model (News.php):

```
    <?php

class News extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'aac_news';

    protected $fillable = array('author', 'title', 'content');
    public $timestamps = true;
}
```

my controller:

```
        <?php

    class AdminController extends BaseController {



    /**
     * News Repository
     *
     * @var News
     */
    protected $news;

    public function __construct(News $news)
    {
        $this->news = $news;
    }

/** ------------------------------------------
 *  News Functions
 *  ------------------------------------------
 */

    public function get_news()
    {

      return View::make('admin.news_managment')->with('newss', $this->news->all());
    }

    public function create_news()
    {

      return View::make('admin.create_news');
  }

  public function post_create_news()
  {
    $input = Input::all();

    $rules = array(
        'author' => 'required|min:4|max:255',
        'title' => 'required|unique:aac_news,title|min:4|max:255',
        'content' => 'required|unique:aac_news,content|min:10'
        );

    $validation = Validator::make($input, $rules);

    if ($validation->fails()) {

       return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validation);

   } else {

    News::create($input);
    return Redirect::to('news/index');
}
}

public function news_delete($newsId)
{
 $news = $this->news->findOrFail($newsId);
 $news->delete();
 return Redirect::back()->with('success', 'Your news post has been deleted.');
}
}
```

and my routes:

```
    # News Management
Route::get('admin/dash/news', 'AdminController@get_news');
Route::get('admin/dash/news/add', 'AdminController@create_news');
Route::post('admin/dash/news/add', 'AdminController@post_create_news');
Route::get('admin/dash/news/{id}/delete/', 'AdminController@news_delete');
```

It just returns my custom error 404 page. There are no errors in my console (laravel's PHP). I have the same function to delete my account, and it works.

Comment: Which URL are you accessing?

Comment: @Raphael_
it's an button: `<a class="btn btn-danger" href="{{ URL::action('NewsController@delete', ['id' => $news->id]) }}"><i class="icon-trash icon-large"></i> Delete</a>`

Comment: You're trying to redirect to `NewsController@delete`, but what you really want is `AdminController@news_delete`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried just finding the item using your `News` class?

```
public function news_delete($newsId)
{
    $news = News::find($newsId);
    $news->delete();
    return Redirect::back()->with('success', 'Your news post has been deleted.');
}
```

Though really you should check that it was deleted before you tell the user so.  The `delete()` method returns the number of affected rows, so you should check if it's more than `0` when it comes back

Comment: you mean just trying News::find($newsId)? Also, I should put the delete method before or? haven't really checked if it's more than 0 when it comes back, beacuse it worked on my account deletion system.

Comment: sorry. yes.. should be just `find()` (will update above!).  `delete()` has to come after, as only then will you have retrieved that record

Comment: He was using the `News` class already using dependency injection. How is this solution different?